# Err: Node 127.0.0.1:6379 is not configured as a cluster node while creating Redis Cluster

Tags: ruby, redis, node-redis, redis-cluster

I am creating Redis cluster by running following command

```
redis-trib.rb create --replicas 1 127.0.0.1:6379 127.0.0.1: 6380 127.0.0.1: 6381 127.0.0.1: 6382 127.0.0.1:6383 127.0.0.1:6384
```

I have already created 6 instances of Redis node running on the same server on different port i.e. on 6379, 6380, 6381, 6382, 6383, 6384 respectively.

Now while executing the above command I am getting error that Node 127.0.0.1:6379 is not configured as a cluster node.

I have also changed the configuration in **redis.windows-service.conf** file for following keys

```
  cluster-enabled yes

  appendonly yes
```

Windows service for all 6 noded is also up and running.

I found some discussion here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/7PCu4-pnt9s regarding similar type issue with no luck.

Is anyone has some idea what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution by Myself by some troubleshooting steps. The problem was that all the Redis slots were not coverd. By deleting the log files and executing command to cover slot resolves the problem.

Helpful link : http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial